# Why the result of download for Sentinel-2 Cloud Removal doesn't show reflectance value?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api, reflectance

I succeed to remove cloud from these step in :

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless

Then I download the result. But, the result is not in decimal as reflectance value. It is float64. While in the statement in the website : This tutorial is an introduction to masking clouds and cloud shadows in Sentinel-2 (S2) surface reflectance (SR) data using Earth Engine.

I download using this code :

```
# download part of band
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
  image=s2_sr_median.select('B3')
  description='2019_3',
  folder='ee_demos',
  region=region,
  scale=10,
  crs='EPSG:4326'
  )
task.start()
```

You can see in the drive : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Rx0_nTelEMeUp-YSfhsRDnXeWN0dcMMA?usp=sharing. Am I mistake in writing the code to download reflectance value of sentinel-2 cloud removal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the scale factor is missing. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR), a scale 0.0001 needs to be applied.  From [this segment](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless#display_the_cloud-free_composite) of the tutorial, it is clear that the scale factor is not applied. The following code is supposed to work.

```
s2_sr_median = (s2_sr_cld_col.map(add_cld_shdw_mask)
                             .map(apply_cld_shdw_mask)
                             .median().divide(10000))
```